# Should we normalize the dataset before fitting the Gumbel distribution?

Tags: r, distributions, normalization, gumbel-distribution

I tried to test if I should normalize the dataset before doing distribution fitting.

```
> a1 <- rgev(2000, loc= 0.449, scale=0.7423, shape=0)
> a1_scale <- scale(a1)
> fgev(a1, shape=0)

Call: fgev(x = a1, shape = 0) 
Deviance: 5159.472 

Estimates
   loc   scale  
0.4619  0.7495  

Standard Errors
    loc    scale  
0.01764  0.01307  

Optimization Information
  Convergence: successful 
  Function Evaluations: 24 
  Gradient Evaluations: 5 

> fgev(a1_scale, shape=0)

Call: fgev(x = a1_scale, shape = 0) 
Deviance: 5288.283 

Estimates
    loc    scale  
-0.4476   0.7740  

Standard Errors
    loc    scale  
0.01822  0.01350  

Optimization Information
  Convergence: successful 
  Function Evaluations: 24 
  Gradient Evaluations: 5
```

To check the agreement between these two results, I generate model b from the parameters obtained above and do the qq-plot.

```
> b1 <- rgev(2000, loc=0.4619, scale=0.7495, shape=0)
> b1_scale <- rgev(2000, loc=-0.4476, scale=0.7440, shape=0)
> qqplot(b1, b1_scale)
> abline(0,1)
```

Here is what I found:

[image]

Does it mean that I should never normalize the dataset before doing distribution fitting?